# Swipe between Activities by touch in android

Tags: java, android

how can i let user swipe between pages by touch in android
i am using android 2.1

i found this Link but i am not sure ViewPager works with 2.1 
[ViewPager](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html)

so i found Viewflipper and ViewSwitcher.is it doing the same thing as Viewpager?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I think you will get an idea from these links.For swiping a page left and right the best way will be using a customized view.

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-user-interface-design-horizontal-view-paging/

https://github.com/grantland/android-horizontalpager

http://savagelook.com/blog/android/swipes-or-flings-for-navigation-in-android

http://blog.sephiroth.it/2011/04/04/imageview-zoom-and-scroll/

Horizondalpager is the best option.Hope this will help you to get there :-)

Comment: There is already a supported method of doing this using Google's own support library. Third party libraries are no longer required and are not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

[Viewpager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) is the one you want to use and does work with 2.1 (It is part of the backwards compatible support library)

Viewflipper does not allow you to swipe. It simply switches one view with another on demand.

Comment: so my link is it complete and useful?because i do not understand the Compatible part?if u can please tell me about the compatible more.

Comment: in compatible part, press rightclick choose ‘Android Tools’ and ‘Add Compatibility Library’ so that is it?

Comment: Yes that will add it to your project. Full details here: http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html

Comment: so my tutorial is it complete?

Comment: and if you have a best tutorial please provide me